# React-masonry-component in Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs, masonry

I'm having trouble installing [React-masonry-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component) in Meteor using cosmos:browserify. The error message indicates no compatible version of the component's dependency, masonry, can be found (in npm, I believe). The same react package seems to work in a regular node project using Webpack, which is why I believe this issue is Meteor specific.

Here is my packages.json file.

```
{
  "externalify": "0.1.0",
  "react-router": "0.13.3",
  "react-pixi": "0.6.1",
  "radium": "0.13.4",
  "griddle-react": "0.2.13",
  "react-masonry-component": "1.0.1"
}
```

app.browserify.js

```
ReactRouter = require("react-router");
ReactPIXI = require("react-pixi");
Radium = require("radium");
Griddle = require("griddle-react");
Masonry = require("react-masonry-component");
```

Error message during build process

```
=> Modified -- restarting.
npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- externalify, react-router,
react-pixi, radium, griddle-react, masonry-layout, imagesloaded,
react-masonry-component...
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv
"C:\\Users\\Nick\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.1.4\\mt-    os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\Nick\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.1.4\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install" "react-masonry-component@1.0.1"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.3
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found:
masonry@'git+ssh://git@github.com/eiriklv/masonry.git'
**npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.0.1","0.0.2"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are
requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of
'react-masonry-component'
npm ERR! notarget


=> Errors prevented startup:

   While building package npm-container:
   error: couldn't install npm package

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Comment from React-Masonry component author,Eirik:  "There seems to be an issue when trying to install dependencies from github and not just npm, since it’s trying to install this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/masonry which is available in version 0.0.1 and 0.0.2, when it should be install https://github.com/eiriklv/masonry.

From this link: https://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor it seems that you can only specify a numbered version, which makes me think that the npm support is limited in some sort."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Meteorhacks:npm requires a specific version/commit of npm or github module, the Meteor build process failed to include this React-Masonry-Component whose package.json defines dependency without referring to a specific commit. For example,

```
"dependency": {"masonry" = "eirik/masonry"}
```

To avoid this issue, I forked Eirik's npm module and published a version that defines all of it's dependency with either a specific npm version or github commit. For example,

```
"dependency": {"masonry" = "https://github.com/eirik/masonry/archive/dd74b7c6fe58e9f5de56d2ab442ac4b2d0fa5dd1.tar.gz"}
```

See https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm for more detail on this requirement.

The code now works with the following settings:

packages.json

```
"react-masonry-component-4meteorhacks-npm": "0.0.13"
```

app.browserify.js

```
Masonry = require("react-masonry-component-4meteorhacks-npm")(React);
```